# 2 networks, but name resolution fully works only for one network

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, ping, nslookup

I have a Windows 2012 Server with DNS configured, on vmware workstation.

Name Server is "ad.nuglab.local", with "Host (A)" record of 172.16.202.109 and 192.168.1.111

On my host PC, with dns server set to 172.16.202.109, I can ping/nslookup/browse any hosts configured on Windows Server, like "esxi-1" that points to 192.168.1.101.

```
> nslookup esxi-1.nuglab.local
Server:  ad.nuglab.local
Address:  172.16.202.109

Name:    esxi-1.nuglab.local
Address:  192.168.1.101

> ping -a 192.168.1.101

Pinging esxi-1.nuglab.local [192.168.1.101] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.101: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.101: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
```

Browser : 
https://esxi-1.nuglab.local -> Resolved.

But, if on my host PC, I change the dns server to 192.168.1.111, name resolution does not fully works. Here's what I get :

I first do `ipconfig /flushdns`

```
> nslookup esxi-1.nuglab.local
Server:  ad.nuglab.local
Address:  192.168.1.111

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Name:    esxi-1.nuglab.local
Address:  192.168.1.101

> ping -a 192.168.1.101

Pinging 192.168.1.101 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.101: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.101: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
```

Browser : 
https://esxi-1.nuglab.local -> Unresolved.

So, nslookup found "192.168.1.101" after two "DNS request timed out".
And ping was not able to resolve the name, but it could ping the resource.

What can explain why it does not work when I choose my dns address to be 192.168.1.111 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My host PC is physically on the "172..." network, and only virtually for "192...".

The Windows Server VM is bridged on the 172 network, and have a "host-only" interface for the "192..."

On the host PC, I needed to add the DNS server address on the "192..." network adapter (not the "172...").

Answer (score 0):

AD DNS Server with 2 nics is not recommended, look at this: https://www.petri.com/configure-dns-on-domain-controller-two-ip-addresses

Comment: Thanks but it's not working. I've deselected "Register this connection’s addresses in DNS" for all interfaces except "192...".  And I've configured DNS server to listen only on "192...".   Still, cannot use the "192..." interface for DNS.  What am I missing ?